# Form Has No Javascript Functionality When Displayed In Colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I have a form with drop-down hierarchical fields with functionality derived from a JavaScript plugin called mcDropdown jQuery Plug-in.

The actual form is on a secondary page (Test.php) and set up to display on the main page through a Colorbox popup with the results also displayed in the Colorbox upon form submission.

The form submits and displays correctly in the Colorbox in its native HTML format when the JavaScript is removed (i.e. just using plain drop-down boxes).

However, when the Javascript is implemented in the form allowing the hierarchial drop-down structure of the fields there is no JS functionality when rendered through Colorbox.

Since the actual page that the form is on (Test.php) works fine by itself with the Javascript, there appears to be some issue rendering the JS through the Colorbox.

My research has indicated that this may be due to trying to access an element before it has been loaded into the document.

The Colorbox website states that this can be resolved by moving the JavaScript into ColorBox's onComplete callback; however, even with the example given, I cannot figure out how to do this correctly as I am a complete novice when it comes to JS.

Here is the drop-down script on the secondary page that has the form and ties into the external plugin (note that there are three fields in this form that use this JS hierarchical configuration):

```
<script type="text/javascript">             

         $(document).ready(function (){
            $("#category").mcDropdown("#categorymenu",
                {
                targetColumnSize: 3,
                }
            );
            $("#category1").mcDropdown("#categorymenu1",
                {
                targetColumnSize: 3,
                }
            );
        $("#category2").mcDropdown("#categorymenu2",
                {
                targetColumnSize: 3,
                }
            );

             });


</script>
```

Here is the Colorbox script on the main page that opens the secondary page in the Colorbox window:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> <!--<Check-Out Colorbox Script>-->

  jQuery(function(){

   jQuery('#link_content').colorbox({opacity:0.3, height:"100%", scrolling: false, onComplete: function(){
    link_content_submit();
  }});
   });
function link_content_submit()
{
  jQuery("#pre-process").submit(function(){
    jQuery.post(
      jQuery(this).attr('action'),
      jQuery(this).serialize(),
      function(data){
        jQuery().colorbox({html: data, onComplete: function(){
          link_content_submit();
        }});
      }
    );
    return false;
  });

  }
</script>
```

The three external files are: jquery.mcdropdown.js, jquery-1.2.6.min.js and jquery.bgiframe.js.

How can this Colorbox script on the main page be modified so the JS functionality of the form is preserved when displayed through Colorbox?

Thank you in advance for any detailed answers for this beginner.

Comment: jquery one point *two*?  You might want to consider dropping [mcdropdown](http://www.givainc.com/labs/mcdropdown_jquery_plugin.htm) in favor of something that's actually *maintained*...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> <!--<Check-Out Colorbox Script>-->

  jQuery(function(){

   jQuery('#link_content').colorbox({opacity:0.3, height:"100%", scrolling: false, onComplete: function(){
    link_content_submit(), $('#category').mcDropdown('#categorymenu'),$('#category1').mcDropdown('#categorymenu1'),$('#category2').mcDropdown('#categorymenu2');
  }});
   });
function link_content_submit()
{
  jQuery("#pre-process").submit(function(){
    jQuery.post(
      jQuery(this).attr('action'),
      jQuery(this).serialize(),
      function(data){
        jQuery().colorbox({html: data, onComplete: function(){
          link_content_submit();
        }});
      }
    );
    return false;
  });

  }
</script>
```

The respective JavaScript functions for each drop-down box in the JS form are integrated into the Colorbox onComplete: function() so each of these form elements is loaded before it is accessed through Colorbox.